# How can I make a copy of a table with a PK?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In an Oracle 10g database, I would like to make a copy of an existing table. I would like it to have the same data and rows as the original table. The original table uses a PK though, so I'm not sure how to copy it and keep them unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the copy using

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_copy as SELECT * FROM dummy//Structure and data
```

Also you could use **dbms_metadata.get_ddl** to get the associated constraints of the table
and create it with all the checks

```
 SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'dummy' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 5):

oracle maintains the pk as a column constraint. you have to copy the table and subsequently create this constraint for the new table.

the following code illustrates how to get your job done.

```
  -- setting up table t1 - this is just for the sake of demonstration
  create table t1 (
        t_id  integer
      , t_data   varchar2(40)
  );
  alter table t1 modify ( t_id constraint t1_pk primary key );

  insert into t1 values ( 1, 'test');
  insert into t1 values ( 2, 'another test');
  insert into t1 values ( 3, 'final test');
  commit;

  -- copying table t1 (definition + contents) and defining the pk
  create table t2 as ( select * from t1 );
  alter table t2 modify ( t_id constraint t2_pk primary key );
```

hope this helps,

best regards,

carsten

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do it all in one statement:

```
create table mike_temp_1 (
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4,
  col5,
  constraint xpk_mike_temp_1 primary key (col1)
)
as select *
from OLD_POLICY_TERM;
```

I think the format of specifying column names when using `create table as select` is a bit fiddly in that I don't believe that you can specify data types (sort of obvious really) but you can specify constraints such as `not null`, primary key and foreign key.