# Create a copy of table and provide constraints to it while creating

Tags: sql, database, oracle, copy, constraints

I am new to Oracle database. I know we can create a copy of table using 
`CREATE TABLE copy_emp(eid, ename,job,mid,sal,dept_id)
as SELECT employee_id, concat(first_name,last_name),job_id,manager_id,salary,department_id FROM employees;`
and later we can use
`alter table copy_emp add constraint epk FORIEGN KEY(dept_id) references departments(dept_id)` to add a foreign key constraint

But is it possible to provide constraints at the time of creating copy of table through query.

For example can we do something like this:

```
CREATE table copy_emp(eid, ename,job,mid,sal,dept_id constraint dpt_fk references copy_dept(department_id) ON DELETEcascade)
as
SELECT employee_id,
concat(first_name,last_name),job_id,manager_id,salary,department_id 
FROM employees;
```

Can we provide constraints while creating a copy of table if yes than what is the query and if no than why?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634163/1156452

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that; your second statement (slightly fixed) will get

```
ORA-02440: Create as select with referential constraints not allowed
02440. 00000 -  "Create as select with referential constraints not allowed"
*Cause:    create table foo (... ref. con. ...) as select ...;
*Action:   Create the table as select, then alter the table to add the
           constraints afterwards.
```

This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__GUID-1299B8D7-58B6-4A15-8B2D-3BBB17A1259F):

> **Restrictions on the Defining Query of a Table**
>
> The table query is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The number of columns in the table must equal the number of expressions in the subquery.
> - The column definitions can specify only column names, default values, and integrity constraints, not data types.
> - You cannot define a foreign key constraint in a `CREATE TABLE` statement that contains `AS subquery` unless the table is reference partitioned and the constraint is the table's partitioning referential constraint. In all other cases, you must create the table without the constraint and then add it later with an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Other constraints can be supplied, as in the answer @Jeff linked to in a comment, so you could add a primary key:

```
CREATE table copy_emp(eid primary key, ename,job,mid,sal,dept_id)
as
SELECT employee_id,
concat(first_name,last_name),job_id,manager_id,salary,department_id 
FROM employees;
```

or (as long as the constraint name is unique)

```
CREATE table copy_emp(eid, ename,job,mid,sal,dept_id,
  constraint emp_pk primary key (eid))
as
SELECT employee_id,
concat(first_name,last_name),job_id,manager_id,salary,department_id 
FROM employees;
```